# Scan word document for images, copy and paste into Excel tabs

Tags: r, excel, vba, ms-word

I have several technical documents that are 200+ pages that I would like to scan over, copy images/figures from, and paste into separate Excel tabs, one for each image/figure. Is there a means to do this with VBA or maybe a scripted language like R?

Apologies if this is somewhat duplicative to other questions asked. However, I don't see a specific question re copying images. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could solve this by writing a short VBA macro that iterates over all (inline) images, copies them to the clipboard and then pastes each into a new sheet in Excel:

```
Sub CopyPicturesToExcel()

    Dim oExcel As Excel.Application
    Dim oWorkbook As Excel.Workbook
    Dim oSheet As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim oInlineShape As inlineShape

    Set oExcel = New Excel.Application
    oExcel.Visible = True
    Set oWorkbook = oExcel.Workbooks.Add

    For Each oInlineShape In ActiveDocument.InlineShapes
        oInlineShape.Range.Copy
        Set oSheet = oWorkbook.Sheets.Add(After:=oWorkbook.Sheets(oWorkbook.Sheets.Count))
        oSheet.Paste
    Next

    ' remove the empty first sheet
    oWorkbook.Sheets(1).Delete

End Sub
```

Comment: One more quick question, this is throwing an error, saying:
'Paste' of object '_Worksheet' failed.

I am not sure what is causing the error, after trying to troubleshoot several times. Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: Sounds like the clipboard contains a worksheet instead of the picture from the Word document. Are you certain that you copy the correct object(s)?